# How to convert Tensorflow .pb models to Tensforflow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, model

I need to convert a **tensorflow pb** model into **tensorflow lite**, by using [Google CoLab](https://colab.research.google.com/).

The conversion procedures are next:

1) To upload the model:

```
from google.colab import files
pbfile = files.upload()
```

2) To convert it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
pb_file = 'data_513.pb'
tflite_file = 'data_513.tlite'

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(pb_file, ['ImageTensor'], ['SemanticPredictions'], 
                                                      input_shapes={"ImageTensor":[1,513,513,3]})

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

The conversion fails with the next error

**Check failed: array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array "ImageTensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float).**

I think I may need to specify some extra commands to overcome this error, but I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Here the snipped for others to use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
pb_file = 'model.pb'
tflite_file = 'model.tflite'

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(pb_file, ['ImageTensor'], ['SemanticPredictions'], 
                                                      input_shapes={"ImageTensor":[1,513,513,3]})


converter.inference_input_type=tf.uint8
converter.quantized_input_stats = {'ImageTensor': (128, 127)}  # (mean, stddev)

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model) 

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

files.download(tflite_file)
```